# How to implement LayoutTemplate with a PlaceHolder

Tags: asp.net, controls, placeholder, itemplate

In my own server control, I would like to implement something similar to the `ListView`:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I have created an `ITemplate` property, I can set the layout in the aspx page, and I am doing `ITemplate.InstantiateIn(myControl)`.

But I can't figure out how to insert controls at the placeholder.  I'm guessing it would be something like `MyTemplate.FindControl("itemPlaceholder").Controls.Add(myControl)`.  I tried casting to the type of my `ITemplate`, but I get the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder' to type 'MyNamespace.MyLayoutTemplate'
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**  I just found this: http://www.nikhilk.net/SingleInstanceTemplates.aspx  `Control developers can define templates to be single instance using metadata which causes the ID'd controls within the template contents to be promoted to the page level... The parser and code-generator together work behind the scenes to add member fields, and initialize them at the right time.`.   It seems to be only for user controls?  I tried `Page.FindControl()` after doing this but it didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was simply a matter of **user error**.  I instantiated the `ITemplate` in a `Panel`, so obviously `Page.FindControl()` (which is not recursive) wouldn't work.  Once I did `Panel.FindControl()`, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used this library with sucess 
http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

Comment: That looks like it's for persisting controls in a placeholder across postbacks.  I can't even add controls... I need to somehow get a reference to the `PlaceHolder` in my `ITemplate` so that I can do `Controls.Add()`